# Insert SCOPE_IDENTITY at time of insert

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am using SQL Server 2008. Here is my sample table

```
 SEQ   NAME  GROUP
  1    abc   1
  2    bcd   1
  3    cde   3
```

In the above table, SEQ is my identity column (auto number). If I want to insert a new row with name = 'def' and group = 3, I can do it as follows

```
INSERT INTO SampleTable(NAME, GROUP) VALUES ('def',3)
```

Now, if I want to insert a new row and then set GROUP = SEQ of the newly inserted row, I am doing it in two steps as shown below

```
INSERT INTO SampleTable(NAME, GROUP) VALUES ('def',999)
UPDATE SampleTable SET GROUP = SEQ where NAME = 'def'
```

Is there any way to do it in a single step? For example

```
INSERT INTO SampleTable(NAME, GROUP) VALUES ('def',SCOPE_IDENTITY())
```

The above statement obviously doesn't work since SCOPE_IDENTITY() is set only after the insert has completed. But is there any way to set GROUP = SEQ using a single insert statement?

Comment: Any particular reason this must be done in a single command?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: @YuriyGalanter - No. I was just seeing if there is a better or more elegant way to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A minor improvement would be changing the `UPDATE` to filter on `SEQ`:

```
INSERT INTO SampleTable(NAME, GROUP) VALUES ('def',999)
UPDATE SampleTable SET GROUP = SEQ where SEQ = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

I like this better because we are likely to get a clustered index seek by filtering on `SEQ`. Also, I think it is semantically cleaner.

I don't know of any way to do this in one statement with an `IDENTITY` column (even thinking about `OUTPUT` and `MERGE` nothing comes to mind). You can do it with a SQL Server 2012 `SEQUENCE` though by using the `INSERT...SELECT` syntax. In the select part, you pop one number from the sequence and copy it into two columns.

Comment: I like the performance improvement suggestion! Since there seems to be no way to do it in a single statement, I will continue using the dual statement approach but with the improvement you suggested. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can make Group a computed column and set its value to be SEQ while creating the table itself.Then you just need to insert NAME and both SEQ and GROUP will be set automatically

Comment: That would work only if GROUP was always the same as SEQ or if GROUP could always be computed from SEQ. For my use case, it can sometimes be the same as SEQ and sometimes different